# SQL combine relationship table as separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this 2 tables

```
 Items
 ID     Type     ClientID
 ========================
 1      0        123
 2      0        123

 Texts
 ItemID   Language     Text
 ================================
 1        Eng          Hi there!
 1        Spa          Holla!
 2        Eng          bye!
 2        Spa          bye in Spanish!
```

In my final result I wat the SQL to return me this table

```
 ID      Type    Eng           Spa
 ================================
 1       0        Hi there!     Holla!
 2       0         Bye!          bye in Spanish!
```

I tried to create this statement:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT I.ID ,I.Type,
 (SELECT T.Text WHERE D.Language='Eng') AS 'Eng',
 (SELECT T.Text WHERE D.Language='Spa') AS 'Spa'
 FROM Items I
 INNER JOIN Texts T ON I.ID=T.ItemID
```

but i get this result:

```
 ID      Type    Eng           Spa
 ================================
 1       0        Hi there!     NULL
 1       0        NULL          Holla!
 2       0        Bye!          NULL
 2       0        NULL          bye in Spanish!
```

Comment: Join with texts twice.

Comment: Sorry for that guys - I need the join because i need the type from Items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why a join is necessary.  You can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.itemid,
       max(case when t.language = 'Eng' then t.text end) as Eng,
       max(case when t.language = 'Spa' then t.text end) as Spa
from texts t
group by t.itemid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nesting to make two joins on same table with a filter (where clause) .
Below i have tested on MySQL

```
SELECT 
    i.id, eng_table.text AS eng, spa_table.text AS spa
FROM
    i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        ItemID AS ID, Text
    FROM
        t
    WHERE
        Language = 'ENG') AS eng_table ON i.id = eng_table.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        ItemID AS ID, Text
    FROM
        t
    WHERE
        Language = 'SPA') AS spa_table ON i.id = spa_table.id
```

Regards,
Bikxs

Answer (score 0):

A solution using joins would look something like....

```
Select i.ID 
      ,i.[Type]
      ,t1.[Text] AS [Eng]
      ,t2.[Text] AS [Spa]
FROM Items i 
INNER JOIN Texts t1 ON i.ID = t1.ItemID AND t1.[Language] = 'Eng'
INNER JOIN Texts t2 ON i.ID = t2.ItemID AND t2.[Language] = 'Spa'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Eng
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Texts t WHERE t.Language = 'Eng'
),
Spa
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Texts t WHERE t.Language = 'Spa'
)
SELECT i.ID, i.Type, e.Text AS Eng, s.Text AS Spa
FROM Items i 
LEFT JOIN Eng e ON i.ID = e.ItemID
LEFT JOIN Spa s ON i.ID = s.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you can use a dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @query = 'SELECT t1.itemid, MAX(t2.[Type]) AS [Type], ' + 
      STUFF
      (
         (
            SELECT DISTINCT ',MAX(CASE WHEN t1.[language] =  '''+ [language] 
              + ''' THEN t1.[Text] END) AS ' + [Language]
            FROM Texts 
            FOR XML PATH('')
          ),
      1,1,'');
SELECT @query += ' FROM texts t1 JOIN items t2 ON t1.ItemId = t2.ID GROUP BY t1.itemid;';

EXECUTE(@query);
```